# What can I use to simulate user actions within firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, automation, script

Is there a tool/scripting language that would permit me to run a script in firefox?
It is for page testing -- Ideally I could release a version, and it would simulate the user by waiting, clicking, inputting content, and also had some ability to do logging/email of results.

I know I could use auto-it, but I would like to use something specific to Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its called **Automated Web Testing**, and as I am a C# developer, I use [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/). You may find [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) interesting too.

[This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417380/watin-or-selenium) may help you getting a clear idea.

Answer (score 2):

I found greaseMonkey -- I should have known that!

Answer (score 1):

There is the [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3863) add-on for Firefox. Not sure if it's exactly what you need, but it allows you to record a series of actions and play them back in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is better for automate . It has record and playback option.